# How to count all the products that belongs to category(slug) Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel. I need a little help.
I have an index.blade.php file which displays all the category names. When I click on on it will generate the slug link where I have all the products that in the category. So I would like to count only those products that is belongs to category's slug and display the number on the index.blade.php. Thanks for the help.

```
 Route::get('view-category/{slug}', [ProductsController::class,'viewcategory']);
```

productsController:

```
public function viewcategory($slug){
        if(Category::where('slug', $slug)->exists()){
            $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
            $products = Products::where('cateId', $category->id)->where('status','1')->get();
            return view('admin.products.display', compact('category','products'));
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/dashboard')->with('status',"Slug does not exist");
        }
    }
```

category Model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "categories";
    protected $fullable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'description',
        'status',
        'popular',
    ];
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'id', 'cateId');
    }
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
<thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Sub Category</th>
                <th>Variations</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach($category as $item)
                <tr>
                  <td class="control" tabindex="0"></td>
                  <td>{{$item->products->productName}}</td>
                  <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
                  <td>{{$item->subCategory}}</td>
                  <td>{{$item->counter}}</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still call relationships inside your blade files, so if you have a products relationship setup correctly, you only need to change your index blade to this

```
<td>{{$item->products()->count()</td>
```

If you have categories that don't have any products put this in your blade to check before showing the count (Its an if else statement just inline)

```
 <td>{{$item->products ? $item->products()->count() : 'N/A'}}</td>
```

Comment: Small suggestion for improvement. `$item->products->count()` will load the related models into a collection and then call the `Collection` method `count` on it. If you don't need the products, or there are a lot of them, this could be much slower than needed. My suggestion would be to use `$item->products()->count()` which would use the relationship's query builder (`select count(*)` instead of `select *`) so that no product models are hydrated.

Comment: Great suggestion, didn't think in that direction at the time.

Comment: Brian Thompso Thank you so mutch i had a big hadeache with this and you give me a line of code that easely sortout my problem. Suuuuppppeeeerrrrr!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

in your blade file add this line before your foreach

```
   @if( $category->posts->count() )
   //your @foreach code here
   @endif
```

Comment: What would he get from checking if the count() is larger than 0?

Comment: the number of posts/items under that category if they have an existing relationship

Comment: This one is not working
 Property [posts orwhatever i write here] does not exist on this collection instance. Acctually i do not have posts. I have category slug and products

Comment: Solved by Brian Thompson
Small suggestion for improvement. $item->products->count() will load the related models into a collection and then call the Collection method count on it. If you don't need the products, or there are a lot of them, this could be much slower than needed. My suggestion would be to use $item->products()->count() which would use the relationship's query builder (select count(*) instead of select *) so that no product models are hydrated.